# Unable to find the test case where my program to find largest integer divisible by 3 goes wrong

Tags: java, linked-list, testcase

Recently while i was trying to solve a question where I am given a number of digits between 0 to 9 and have to find the largest integer divisible by 3.

I have read my code again but I am unable to find the test case where it fails. I will be grateful if the good people of stack overflow will help me find that test case. The testcase is a hidden testcase so I can't just print the elemets of the testcase.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class Main {
public int answer(int[] l) {

    int b[] = new int[l.length];
    int divb = 0;
    int div = 0;
    int t = 0;
    int mi = 1;
    int counter = 0;
    LinkedList<Integer> ab = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    Arrays.sort(l);
    for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        ab.add(l[i]); //adding the elements to linkedlist after sorting them 
        div += l[i]; //adding all the elements in the array
        b[i] = l[i] % 3;//we use b[i] to find whether we have 0,1,2 as one of the remainders
        divb += b[i];
        if (b[i] == 2) {
            mi = 0;
        }
        if (b[i] == 1) {
            counter = 1;
        }
    }
    if (div % 3 == 1) { 
        if (counter == 1) {/*if counter is 1 that means we have atleast one element which has remainder 1 where we can remove that element to get a an integer in descending order of its digits which are divisible by 3*/
            for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                if (b[i] == 1) {
                    div -= l[i];
                    ab.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
        } else {//if there is no such digit with remainder 1 but we have a number like 3,6,9 which is divible by 3 then we should return such a number.
            int tk = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                if (b[i] != 0) {
                    div-=l[i];
                    ab.remove(tk);
                    tk--;
                }
                tk++;
            }
        }

        if (div % 3 != 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
        int k[] = new int[2];
        if (div % 3 == 2) {//if the remainder is 2 then we have to remove oen digit with remainder as 2 or two digits with remainder as one. I tried to use various counters so that they don't effect each other

            for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
                if (b[i] == 2 && mi == 0) {
                    div -= l[i];
                    ab.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
                if (b[i] == 1 && t != 2 && mi == 1) {
                    div -= l[i];
                    k[t] = i;
                    t++;
                }
                if (t == 2) {
                    ab.remove(k[0]);
                    ab.remove(k[1] - 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (div % 3 != 0) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        if (ab.size() >= 1) {//Here we will check whether size of result is more than zero just in case there was only element in the array which might have no more elements now.
            int result = 0;
            Integer[] res = ab.toArray(new Integer[ab.size()]);
            for (int i = res.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                result = 10 * result + res[i];
            }
            return result;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    int a[]={7,7,7,6};
    Main d=new Main();
    int f=d.answer(a);
    System.out.print(f);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you modify it to print out the input, so that when the test case fails, you can see what the input was?  Then, use your debugger to find out what happens with that particular input.

Comment: Your problem description is vague and the program is extremely difficult to understand. I eventually gave up trying to understand what it does.

Comment: Why cant you sort the given numbers, and then search for it?

Comment: @Henry I am sorry about not including comments to the code. I have added it now.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Its one of the coding questions with hidden test cases, so i am unable to find the test case where it fails.

Comment: Did you read my comment?  I told you how to find the test case where it fails.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem in that website, using java.lang.system is prohibited. so i can't use to print the input.

Comment: Then I would argue that using that web site is not going to help your learning.  I advise you to start using a different site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When trying to write a tricky algorithm like this it's often a good idea to write a second, simpler implementation to test it against.

In this case the obvious candidate is a brute force approach, where you generate all possible permutations of all possible subsets of your input digits, test if the resulting number is divisible by 3 and keep track of the max such number encountered.

Here's some code that implements this idea:

```
public class BruteDiv3
{
    public static int maxDiv3(int[] arr)
    {
        return generateSubsets(arr, new BitSet(), 0, 0);
    }

    static int generateSubsets(int[] digits, BitSet selected, int pos, int maxDiv3)
    {
        if (pos == digits.length)
        {
            List<Integer> subset = toSubset(digits, selected);
            if (!subset.isEmpty())
            {
                maxDiv3 = permuteSubset(subset, 0, maxDiv3);
            }
            return maxDiv3;
        }

        boolean duplicate = false;
        for (int i = pos - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (digits[i] == digits[pos] && !selected.get(i))
            {
                duplicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!duplicate)
        {
            selected.set(pos);
            maxDiv3 = generateSubsets(digits, selected, pos + 1, maxDiv3);
            selected.clear(pos);
        }

        maxDiv3 = generateSubsets(digits, selected, pos + 1, maxDiv3);

        return maxDiv3;
    }

    static int permuteSubset(List<Integer> subset, int pos, int maxDiv3)
    {
        if (pos == subset.size())
        {
            int num = toInteger(subset);
            if (num % 3 == 0 && num > maxDiv3)
            {
                maxDiv3 = num;
            }
            return maxDiv3;
        }

        maxDiv3 = permuteSubset(subset, pos + 1, maxDiv3);

        for (int i = pos + 1; i < subset.size(); i++)
        {
            if (!subset.get(pos).equals(subset.get(i)))
            {
                List<Integer> permSubset = new ArrayList<>(subset);
                Collections.swap(permSubset, pos, i);
                maxDiv3 = permuteSubset(permSubset, pos + 1, maxDiv3);
            }
        }

        return maxDiv3;
    }

    static List<Integer> toSubset(int[] arr, BitSet on)
    {
        List<Integer> ss = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
            if (on.get(i))
                ss.add(arr[i]);
        }
        return ss;
    }

    static int toInteger(List<Integer> digits)
    {
        int num = 0;
        for (int pow10 = 1, i = digits.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--, pow10 *= 10)
        {
            num += digits.get(i) * pow10;
        }
        return num;
    }
}
```

With this in hand we can now write a routine to compare the numbers from the brute force approach with the numbers from your routine with random input.

```
static void compare(int n)
{
    int[] arr = new int[n];
    Random r = new Random();
    while (true)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            arr[i] = r.nextInt(10);

        int maxBrute = BruteDiv3.maxDiv3(arr);
        int maxSO = new Main().answer(arr);

        if (maxBrute % 3 != 0)
            System.out.println("Bad Brute: " + maxBrute);
        if (maxSO % 3 != 0)
            System.out.println("Bad SO: " + maxSO);

        if (maxBrute != maxSO)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr) + " " + maxBrute + " " + maxSO);
        }
    }
}
```

For input up to n=4 things seem to be OK.

However, by n=5 we get:

```
[2, 5, 5, 5, 8] 855 0
[2, 5, 8, 8, 8] 888 0
[2, 2, 5, 5, 5] 555 0
...
```

Where your routine seems to be returning 0.

For n=8 we have

```
[0, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 8, 8] 885330 330
[2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 5, 9, 9] 995553 993
[2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 6, 9] 965532 963
...
```

Hopefully you can use the above routines to help track down the issues in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I will keep this in mind while trying out algorithms in the future too.